# How do I perform string matching and replacements?

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching, string-manipulation

What are, and how do I use *Mathematica's* string matching and replacement tools?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are three different mechanisms provided for matching string patterns in *Mathematica*.  Each of these must be used within functions that are equipped to handle strings.  You cannot, for instance, use:

```
{"abc", "def", "ghi"} /. "a*" -> 1
Replace["downwind", "downw" -> "resc"]
```

to any effect.  Instead you would use:

```
{"abc", "def", "ghi"} /. x_String /; StringMatchQ[x, "a*"] -> 1
StringReplace["downwind", "downw" -> "resc"]
```

### Simple wildcard matching:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Example:  `StringMatchQ["abcde", "ab*"]` yields `True`.

Wildcards (or "metacharacters") do not work natively in functions such as `StringReplace` and `StringCases` and are usually used with `StringMatchQ`.  They also work with and are useful for simple commands such as `Names["Pre*"]`.

### Regular Expressions

Since version 5.1 *Mathematica* supports [regular expressions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RegularExpression.html).  I am not an expert on regular expression use, and detailed usage information is readily available in both the *Mathematica* documentation and elsewhere, so I leave it to the reader to explore.  RegEx is powerful and popular with those doing a lot of string manipulation, especially for performance.

### StringExpression

Also since version 5.1 there is a paradigm of using familiar *Mathematica* expression patterns for strings, along with a multitude of special named patterns, within a [`StringExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StringExpression.html) object.  It has the short infix form `~~` such that`a ~~ b ~~ c` has the long form `StringExpression[a, b, c]`.

`StringExpression` also accepts patterns in the `RegularExpression` form making it the master method for *Mathematica* string patterns.

A major advantage of this new paradigm is that you can use most of the *Mathematica* pattern elements you should already be familiar with, such as `_`, `__`, `___`, `..`, `...`, `Except`, `Shortest`, `Longest` etc.  You can also name these patterns as you can in expression matching.

Here is a contrived replacement on the start of Lorem ipsum using `Blank`, `Repeated`, `Condition`, and `Pattern`:

```
sample = StringTake[ExampleData[{"Text", "LoremIpsum"}], 200];
```

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Integer nunc
>   augue, feugiat non, egestas ut, rutrum eu, purus. Vestibulum
>   condimentum commodo pede. Nam in metus eu justo commodo posuere. Nun

```
StringReplace[
  sample,
  x_ ~~ y : Repeated[LetterCharacter, 5] ~~ " " /; UpperCaseQ[x] :> "X" <> y <> " "
]
```

> Xorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Integer nunc
>   augue, feugiat non, egestas ut, rutrum eu, purus. Vestibulum
>   condimentum commodo pede. Xam in metus eu justo commodo posuere. Nun

Comment: +1. I think it would be good to mention that patterns are intrinsically more powerful than regexps, since you can construct recursive patterns, so that you can do with patterns things not possible with reg.exps, but this flexibility comes at a price of performance, and performance hit is very substantial, so that one of the most common performance-tuning tricks for string matching is to rewrite patterns using reg.exps.

Comment: Perhaps three nice goodies could be mentioned in your answer: Shortest, Longest and Except

Comment: @Leonid thanks, I'll get on it.

Comment: @belisarius they *are*; or do you mean given in examples?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Sorry, I was writing carelessly. What I tried to say is that some _examples_ could be nice. Sorry again.

Comment: @Leonid I'm having trouble crafting a recursive pattern as you described.  I'll mention the performance advantage of RegEx in my answer (which was an oversight) but it will be better if you post an example where RegEx fails and `StringExpression` succeeds.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It does not come to my mind right now, and I have no more time for it today, but once I have some, I will write a comment, if no one does that before me. One simple thing to try is to parse HTML with patterns - I think it should be possible :)

Comment: @Leonid For examples of string patterns that cannot be implemented (solely) as regex, see the "implementation" section of [Working with String Patterns](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html#337819047)

Comment: @WReach Ok, thanks! This is good to know. I always suspected that there is a conversion to reg.exps, and even wanted to write a converter myself as an excercise. It is good to know that this exists. On a different matter, I think I start to understand how to prompt you to appear (for the benefits of all of us), although this time I did not do it on purpose :). Seriously, I miss you answers these days, and I am sure I am not alone.

Comment: @Leonid Thanks for the kind words :)

Answer (score 16):

Mr.Wizard's answer is of course a nice overview. But one can also answer this question by pointing to the documentation - and I don't mean this as a drive-by answer, but as an actually worth-while activity:

For a nice coherent exposition of all the string matching functionality, do the following:

- open the `Documentation Center`
- Click on the `Book` icon at the top:

[image: book]

Navigate through the sections indicated in this screenshot:

[image: index]

It is a well-written overview, I think.