# Find the position of a string element, knowing only part of the string

Tags: string-manipulation, searching

I have a list, e.g.:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, "Element 1", 4, 5, "Element 2", "Something else 1", "etcetera"}
```

Now, I want all elements starting with `"El"`. Using `Position`, I could find the position of e.g. `"Element 1"`:

```
Position[list, "Element 1"]
```

But, I would like to know the positions of `"Element 1"` and `"Element 2"`, as both start with `"El"`. So, I would like to have something like

```
Position[list, "El"_]
```

I just can't get something like this to work.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need string patterns and Friends, e.g. `StringFreeQ, StringPosition, ..`

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6998/121

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> But I would like to know the **positions** of `"Element 1"` and `"Element 2"`...

You can still use `Position[]`; things are a little more elaborate, though, due to the strings:

```
Position[list, s_String /; StringMatchQ[s, "El*"]]
   {{4}, {7}}

Extract[list, %]
   {"Element 1", "Element 2"}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot - that solved it.

Answer (score 5):

```
Select[list, StringMatchQ[ToString@#, "El" ~~ ___] &]
```

> {"Element 1", "Element 2"}

Answer (score 3):

A possibility:

```
Cases[list, x_String /; StringMatchQ[x, "El*"]]
```

> ```
> {"Element 1", "Element 2"}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

> But, I would like to know the positions of "Element 1" and "Element
> 2", as both start with "El"

[image]

Some possibilities using `StringStartsQ` could be:

```
list = {1, 2, 3, "Element 1", 4, 5, "Element 2", "Something else 1", 
   "etcetera"};

Extract[list, Position[list, _String?(StringStartsQ[#, "El"] &)]]

Cases[list, _String?(StringStartsQ[#, "El"] &)]

Select[list, StringQ] // Select[StringStartsQ["El"]]

Select[list, StringQ[#] && StringStartsQ[#, "El"] &]

SequenceCases[list, {x_String /; StringStartsQ[x, "El"]} :> x]
```

This being mixed `Head` list, a pre-selection of `String` heads is required to silence the warnings and errors.

---

*Result:*

> {"Element 1", "Element 2"}

Answer (score 1):

Using `DeleteCases` and `Except`:

```
DeleteCases[list, Except[x_String /; StringStartsQ[x, "El"]]]

(*{"Element 1", "Element 2"}*)
```