# Finding the position of strings in a list that contain a particular word/string sequence

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

If I have a list of strings Like:

```
text = Select[
  StringSplit[
   StringReplace[
    StringTake[ExampleData[{"Text", "AliceInWonderland"}], {25, 997}], 
    Alternatives @@ Characters["<>?;'|:\"()-_!&"] -> " "], "." | ","],
   StringLength[#] > 2 &]
```

> {"Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on
>   the bank"," and of having nothing to do"," Once or twice she had
>   peeped into the book her sister was reading"," but it had no pictures
>   or conversations in it","  and what is the use of a book","  thought
>   Alice","  without pictures or conversations   So she was considering
>   in her own mind  as well as she could"," for the day made her feel
>   very sleepy and stupid "," whether the pleasure of making a daisy
>   chain would be worth the trouble of getting up and picking the
>   daisies"," when suddenly a White Rabbit with pink eyes ran close by
>   her"," There was nothing so very remarkable in that"," nor did Alice
>   think it so very much out of the way to hear the Rabbit say to
>   itself","  Oh dear  Oh dear  I shall be too late   But when the Rabbit
>   actually took a watch out of its waistcoat pocket and looked at it and
>   then hurried on"," Alice started to her feet"," for it flashed across
>   her mind that she had never before seen a rabbit with "}

how do I find the positions of the list elements that contain the following words/character strings:

```
words = {"her", "she", "alice", "bbit"};
```

Following on from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25002/find-the-position-of-a-string-element-knowing-only-part-of-the-string) question, I tried using `Position` like so:

```
Position[text, 
 s_ /; StringMatchQ[s, __ ~~ Alternatives @@ words ~~ __, 
    IgnoreCase -> True] &]
```

> {}

but this doesn't produce the list of positions. The follwing seems to suggest that I have the right string-matching criteria:

```
StringMatchQ[text, __ ~~ Alternatives @@ words ~~ __, 
 IgnoreCase -> True]
```

> {True,False,True,False,False,False,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True,True}

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`StringPosition[]` supports the useful form:

> StringPosition[ {string1, string2 ...},  {patt1, patt2, ...} ]

So:

```
Position[StringPosition[text, words, IgnoreCase -> True], Except@{}, 1, Heads -> False]
```

> {{1}, {3}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {11}, {12}, {13}, {14}, {15}}

**Edit**

This approach seems much faster than using conditional pattern matching:

```
text = Join @@ Array[Select[StringSplit[StringReplace[StringTake[
               ExampleData[{"Text", "AliceInWonderland"}], {25, 997}], 
              Alternatives @@ Characters["<>?;'|:\"()-_!&"] -> " "], 
              "." | ","], StringLength[#] > 2 &] &, 1000];
words = {"her", "she", "alice", "bbit"}; 

First@Timing@Position[
    text,
    s_ /; StringMatchQ[s, ___ ~~ Alternatives @@ words ~~ ___, IgnoreCase -> True],
    Heads -> False]

First@Timing@Position[
    StringPosition[text, words, IgnoreCase -> True],
    Except@{},
    1, Heads -> False]

First@Timing@Position[
    StringMatchQ[text, ___ ~~ Alternatives @@ words ~~ ___, IgnoreCase -> True],
    True]
```

> 0.168
>   0.042
>   0.044

Comment: Using the listability of `StringMatchQ` it gets comparable speeds: `Position[StringMatchQ[text, ___ ~~ Alternatives @@ words ~~ ___, IgnoreCase -> True], True]` or `Pick[Range[Length[text]], 
 StringMatchQ[text, ___ ~~ Alternatives @@ words ~~ ___, IgnoreCase -> True]]`

Comment: @ssch Could you edit my answer comparing the three methods?

Answer (score 5):

I misunderstood the question first...

I think you want to get rid of the `&` in `Position`:

```
Position[text, 
         s_ /; StringMatchQ[s, ___ ~~ Alternatives @@ words ~~ ___, 
         IgnoreCase -> True], Heads -> False]

(* {{1}, {3}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {11}, {12}, {13}, {14}, {15}} *)
```

As it is  `pattern /; expression` and not `pattern/;function`

**Edit** old answer

You can use [`StringPosition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StringPosition.html):

```
matches = StringPosition[text, Alternatives @@ words]
(* {{{53, 55}}, {}, {{16, 18}, {45, 47}}, {}, {}, {}, {{42, 44}, {65, 
   67}, {90, 92}}, {{19, 21}}, {{6, 8}}, {{26, 29}, {59, 61}}, {{3, 
   5}}, {{67, 70}}, {{58, 61}}, {{19, 21}}, {{12, 14}, {24, 26}, {38, 
   40}, {68, 71}}} *)

MapThread[
 StringReplacePart[#1, ToUpperCase[StringTake[#1, #2]], #2] &,
 {text, matches}]
(* {
  "Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by HER sister on the bank",
  " and of having nothing to do",
  " Once or twice SHE had peeped into the book HER sister was reading",
  " but it had no pictures or conversations in it",
  "  and what is the use of a book", 
  "  thought Alice", 
  "  without pictures or conversations   So SHE was considering in HER own mind  as well as SHE could",
  " for the day made HER feel very sleepy and stupid ",
  " whetHER the pleasure of making a daisy chain would be worth the trouble of getting up and picking the daisies",
  " when suddenly a White RaBBIT with pink eyes ran close by HER",
  " THERe was nothing so very remarkable in that",
  " nor did Alice think it so very much out of the way to hear the RaBBIT say to itself",
  "  Oh dear  Oh dear  I shall be too late   But when the RaBBIT actually took a watch out of its waistcoat pocket and looked at it and then hurried on",
  " Alice started to HER feet", " for it flaSHEd across HER mind that SHE had never before seen a raBBIT with "} *)
```

Comment: You suggestion tells me where these words occur within each list element, but not *which* elements contain any of these words. Also, "alice" wasn't found (simply add `IgnoreCase->True`).

Comment: @geordie how about now? :)

Comment: Yep, that works nicely. Thanks! btw. Why is it necessary to set `Heads -> False`? Is this the same as adding 'levelspec' to `Position`(e.g. `Position[list, blah, {1}]`)?

Comment: It's so it doesn't try to `StringMatchQ[List,...]` changing the pattern to `s_String` would have the same effect. It is distinct from levelspec.

Comment: `text[[6]] == "  thought Alice"` ... Are you missing it?

Comment: Yep, you need two triple underscores in the pattern. I'll edit it.

Comment: @belisarius thanks!