# How to find the line number of a string in an imported `.txt` file?

Tags: import

I have a txt file which contains a lot of data (in fact it's the result file of a .nb file which I have run on a cluster). I want to use the data to plot some graphs in a new .nb file.

Since there are a lot of data in the txt file, it's a really time-consuming task to copy and paste each desired part to the new .nb file, so I decided to put two markers at the start and at the end of each part of data by printing a special word. For example in the original .nb file, I write `Print["start of density data"]` command at the start of density data part, then I print my density function (which shows the data for density as a list), after this I write `Print["end of density data"]`. By doing so, I have determined the start and end of my desired part, then I need to write a code which finds the line number of `"start of density data"`(for example it's 600) and also the line number of `"end of density data"`(for example it's 700).

Now I can write a code to gives me lines 601-699 which contains my desire data. The latter is a straightforward task, but my main problem is how to write a code which finds the line numbers of two markers, I tried `Read` and `Find` after importing my txt file but they don't give line numbers. Any idea?

I have attached a dummy file [here](http://www.deeplook.ir/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/data.txt) to facilitate answering.

Comment: Seems like the easiest solution would be to write the sections of data to separate files. Since you are able to print start/end, this should be easy. Following the link to the dummy file results in "The file you requested has been deleted".

Comment: What do you mean by "write the sections of data to separate files"? Please explain more

Comment: In your original .nb file you print "start" then you print output from `densityFunction` and then you print "end". Instead of printing the `densityFunction`, save its output to a file. `Put[densityFunction[arguments], "some file name"]`. To read it later `densityData = Get["some file name"]`

Comment: Good idea, but I have to save output of 15 functions in each nb file, and I have 63 such nb files, so I need 945 separate files which are soooo much to handle!

Comment: Can you provide a sample file? As I mentioned earlier, the link you provided no longer has the sample.

Comment: I had no access to my laptop right now, but I try to add the file in the next hour

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi I added the dummy file.

Comment: I absolutely agree that it would be much better to write your data to an extra file instead of parsing the notebook for these printed markers. Are you aware that there are various data formats that mathematica can read and write (e.g. HDF5, NetCDF) which will allow you to store more than one dataset? You wouldn't even have to convert the data to strings and back. With that you could certainly have a much more efficient and secure way to save and read your data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. The `Lines` option in `Import` will cause the import of lines as elements of a `Table` object.

```
file = Import["/somePath/data.txt", "Lines"];
Position[file, "\"start of density data\""][[1, 1]]
Position[file, "\"end of density data\""][[1, 1]]
(*
46
48
*)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. What does `"Lines"` do in `import` command?

Comment: @Wisdom It will cause the import of lines as elements of a `Table` object.

Comment: I wonder how your code works by `[[1,1]]` while `file` is not a list. Also when I use this code just for `fvar` without quotation I get the error `"Part 1 of {} does not exist"`, what is the logic of your code?

Comment: I wonder how your code works by `[[1,1]]` while `file` is not a list. Also when I use this code just for `fvar` without double quotation I get the error `"Part 1 of {} does not exist"`, what is the logic of your code? How can I use it for finding line number of any string in the imported file?

Comment: In my test the command `Position[file, "\"start of density data\""]` returns `{{46}}`, thus the need for `[[1,1]]`. If what you want is the number of a line that *contains* some word/string you may have to replace `"\"start of density data\""` by some pattern.

Comment: Thanks but when I try `Position[file2, "\"fvar\""]` I get `{}`, Does this code work just for outputs of `Print` command and does not for comments? If so, what is the general way to find line number of every string in the imported file?

Comment: @Wisdom What is `file2`?

Comment: Sorry my mean was `file`

Comment: @Wisdom See the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1):

```
text = Import["~/Downloads/data.txt", "Lines"];

densityPosition = Position[text, "\"start of density data\"" | "\"end of density data\""] + {1, -1}

densityData = Extract[text, densityPosition] // ToExpression
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to find the position of  `fvar`

Comment: In `data.txt`, `fvar` is after "end of density data". So are you asking a different question?

Comment: `fvar` was just a example. Generally I want a code to find any string in an imported file

Comment: Depending on the structure of the imported data (single string or list of strings or ...) you would have to use `Position` or `StringPosition`.

Comment: This is indeed another question. You can have a look at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32855/finding-the-position-of-strings-in-a-list-that-contain-a-particular-word-string . Try `Position[StringMatchQ[file, RegularExpression[".*fvar.*"]], True][[1]]` .

Comment: @A.G. For simple patterns `RegularExpression` is not needed. `StringMatchQ` accepts `*` (zero or more characters) and `@` (one or more characters excluding uppercase letters). Check the 'Details and Options' section in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringMatchQ.html).