# How to import a table of numbers from a .txt file without losing dimensions?

Tags: import

I have a long txt file (which attached [here](http://www.deeplook.ir/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/data-1.txt)). I want to import this file and then use a special line (in this case line 112) to plot a graph. I tried this

```
file = Import["data.txt", "Data"];
den = file[[112]];
den // Dimensions
(*
{303}
*)
```

As you can see it gives me dimensions `{303}` while the real dimensions of `den` must be `{303,2}` I don't know why Mathematica adds an addiional `{}` to `den`. Also when I try `"Lines"` in `Import` command it returns all of line 112 as a string. What is the best way to import line 112 as a real table as what I really need to plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be an unusual file format which mixes different types of output.  `Import` is attempting to read it as a CSV file, which is causing your problem.

Manual inspection suggests that line 112 is a string representation of a Mathematica List, which suggests that the following should work (using the link you provided).  The basic idea is to import the file as a list of strings (one string for each line), and then to interpret the desired line as needed:

```
file = Import[
   "http://www.deeplook.ir/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/data-1.txt", 
   "List"];
den = ToExpression[ file[[112]] ];
Dimensions[den]  (* {201,2} *)
```

*Warning:*  It's generally considered dangerous to `ToExpression` random things on the internet.  I looked at line 112 first to see that it was an innocuous `List`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. `ToExpression` what a useful command. why it may be dangerous?

Comment: Consider what happens if you evaluated `ToExpression` on a string that read `"DeleteFile[\"*\"]"` .... don't try this at home kids....

Comment: @Wisdom As I mentioned in my comments [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/245663/58370), using `Print` to save several WL expressions to a file and then trying to reconstruct them by reading the file as a string is clunky and brittle. Much better to use `Put`, or `PutAppend`, and `Get`.

Comment: Ok. many Thanks