# StringCount in Mathematica

Tags: string-manipulation

```
StringCount["one letters three letters letters one letters letters three letters",
"one" ~~ __ ~~ "three"]
```

gives

```
1
```

because there is the one occurence of "**one** [letters three letters letters one letters letters] **three** [letters]"

It took me some time to understand that Mathematica "thinks" in this way because I expected the value

```
2
```

due to "**one** letters **three** letters letters **one** letters letters **three** letters"

Now I am facing the problem of finding the code that solves this problem in my desired way.

Comment: Use `Shortest[__]`

Comment: See also: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6998/4330