# text analysis: split document in separated lines

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation, regular-expressions

For a text analysis I want to split a large document in separated lines. Then I want to calculated for example the average number of words. A example of the document is the following:

```
text = {"
  1.1 English Language Proficiency Policy
  Since all activities (lectures, seminars, laboratories) at Humber \
are conducted in English, it is essential that all students possess \
strong English:
  
  *writing skills;
  *comprehension skills;
  *speaking skills.
  
  This allows students to cope with the rigours of the academic \
curriculum and to successfully complete any workplace components of \
the program including co-operative education. Therefore, if your \
first language is not English, or if your previous education has been \
conducted in another language, you will be required to demonstrate \
proficiency in English by undertaking and submitting the results of \
one of the following at the level relative to the program(s) to which \
you apply.
  
  Please note that scores for the standardized English language tests:
  
  may vary by program:
  are only valid for a 24-month period from the date of testing.
  
  1.1.2 For any program level
  
  a minimum of three years of full-time study at the secondary school \
level in an English language school system in a country where English \
is considered the primary language (i.e. the primary language of \
instruction and evaluation is English), with acceptable grades in all \
English courses.
  
  a minimum of one full year of successful study in an accredited \
university degree program, an accredited college degree program or \
graduate-level studies at either the university or college level, or
  two full years of successful study in an accredited college diploma \
program in a country and in a postsecondary institution where English \
is the primary language of instruction.
  "}
```

All lines which start with a digit and finish with an end-of-line character without a "."character must be deleted.
Not all lines have an end-of-line ("\n") character.
The end of a line can be recognized by a word boundary followed by a '.' and then a whitespace character. Or the end-of-line is given by ';' or  ':'.
Characters like "(,),*" must be deleted

The desired output is:

> {"since all activities lectures seminars laboratories at Humber are
> conducted in English", "it is essential that all students possess
> strong English, "writing skills","comprehension skills","speaking
> skills","This allows students to cope with the rigours of the academic
> curriculum and to successfully complete any workplace components of
> the program including co-operative education", "Therefore if your
> first language is not English or if your previous education has been
> conducted in another language you will be required to demonstrate
> proficiency in English by undertaking and submitting the results of
> one of the following at the level relative to the programs to which
> you apply", "Please note that scores for the standardized English
> language tests,may vary by program", "are only valid for a 24-month
> period from the date of testing", "a minimum of three years of
> full-time study at the secondary school level in an English language
> school system in a country where English is considered the primary
> language i.e. the primary language of instruction and evaluation is
> English", with acceptable grades in all English courses", "a minimum
> of one full year of successful study in an accredited university
> degree program an accredited college degree program or graduate-level
> studies at either the university or college level or two full years of
> successful study in an accredited college diploma program in a country
> and in a postsecondary institution where English is the primary
> language of instruction"}

I tried many options with RegularExpression but none of them gave the desired output.

Comment: These kind of things are trivially achieved with any of the standard text processing tools (i.e. perl, awk, etc).

Comment: @belisarius true, however such tools, however useful, are not readily available on PCs.  Personally, I think this is justification enough to have access to a Linux box.  Could the question be expanded to "since I've sworn my soul to microsoft, can I do this in M instead of having to search for and install [gawk](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm)?"

Comment: As @belisarius says there are other tools for this but if you prefer to do it using *Mathematica* I suggest avoiding regular expressions and using the standard pattern elements instead.  Please see [(6998)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6998/121) for a very brief overview.  (Presumably if you were already skilled with regular expressions you would be using a different tool and not having this problem.)

Comment: @bobthechemist I've used gawk-like tools for really big projects, and they are a nightmare too. But for quick and dirty tasks they are heaven.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a rough attempt at implementing what you describe, primarily using [`StringSplit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StringSplit.html).

```
Fold[
 Flatten @ StringSplit[##] &,
 StringReplace[text[[1]], "," | "*" :> ""],
 {
  StartOfLine ~~ Whitespace ... ~~ DigitCharacter ~~ Except["\n"] .. ~~ "\n",
  WordBoundary ~~ ("." | ";" | ":") ~~ Whitespace,
  "\n"
 }
] // StringTrim
```

> ```
> {"Since all activities (lectures seminars laboratories) at Humber are conducted in \
> English it is essential that all students possess strong English", "writing skills", \
> "comprehension skills", "speaking skills", "This allows students to cope with the rigours \
> of the academic curriculum and to successfully complete any workplace components of the \
> program including co-operative education", "Therefore if your first language is not \
> English or if your previous education has been conducted in another language you will be \
> required to demonstrate proficiency in English by undertaking and submitting the results \
> of one of the following at the level relative to the program(s) to which you apply", \
> "Please note that scores for the standardized English language tests", "may vary by \
> program", "are only valid for a 24-month period from the date of testing", "a minimum of \
> three years of full-time study at the secondary school level in an English language \
> school system in a country where English is considered the primary language (i.e", "the \
> primary language of instruction and evaluation is English) with acceptable grades in all \
> English courses", "a minimum of one full year of successful study in an accredited \
> university degree program an accredited college degree program or graduate-level studies \
> at either the university or college level or", "two full years of successful study in an \
> accredited college diploma program in a country and in a postsecondary institution where \
> English is the primary language of instruction"}
> ```

Ugly, I must admit, but perhaps it gives you some idea of where to start.

If you run into any specific problems please let me know.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thank you! You`re fantastic as always!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
StringSplit[
 StringReplace[First@text, 
  Shortest[(x : DigitCharacter) ~~ __ ~~ "\n"] | ")" | "(" | "*" -> 
   ""], "." | ";" | "," | ":"]
```

which gives the following somewhat imperfect output:

> {"
>        Since all activities lectures", " seminars", " laboratories at \ Humber are conducted in English", " it is essential that all students
>   \ possess strong English", "
>        writing skills", "    comprehension skills", "    speaking skills", "
>        This allows students to cope with the rigours of the academic \ curriculum and to successfully complete any workplace components of \
>   the program including co-operative education", " Therefore", " if \
>   your first language is not English", " or if your previous education \
>   has been conducted in another language", " you will be required to \
>   demonstrate proficiency in English by undertaking and submitting the \
>   results of one of the following at the level relative to the programs
>   \ to which you apply", "
>        Please note that scores for the standardized English language \ tests", "
>        may vary by program", "    are only valid for a 
>          a minimum of three years of full-time study at the secondary \ school level in an English language school system in a country where \
>   English is considered the primary language i", "e", " the primary \
>   language of instruction and evaluation is English", " with acceptable
>   \ grades in all English courses", "
>        a minimum of one full year of successful study in an accredited \ university degree program", " an accredited college degree program or
>   \ graduate-level studies at either the university or college level", "
>   or    two full years of successful study in an accredited college \
>   diploma program in a country and in a postsecondary institution where
>   \ English is the primary language of instruction", "    "}

I'm not totally clear on what you want, as your requirements seem to contradict your example output, so hopefully you can modify this to do what you need.