# Using Cases to get elements in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following list:

```
list1 = {"O                    21   B21      20   A20      19   D19      0", \
"90  O            -0.28487   1.23835", "91  O            -0.23761   \
1.29381", "92  O            -0.23093   1.19437", "93  O            \
-0.19657   1.53843", "94  O            -0.17235   1.46275", "O        \
            21   B21      20   A20      19   D19      0", "90  O      \
      -0.28601   1.23805", "91  O            -0.23863   1.29489", "92 \
 O            -0.23206   1.19334", "93  O            -0.19730   \
1.53926"}
```

I need only the elements that do not have the expression:  B21, D19, etc....
Like that:

```
list1 = { \
"90  O            -0.28487   1.23835", "91  O            -0.23761   \
1.29381", "92  O            -0.23093   1.19437", "93  O            \
-0.19657   1.53843", "94  O            -0.17235   1.46275",  "90  O      \
      -0.28601   1.23805", "91  O            -0.23863   1.29489", "92 \
 O            -0.23206   1.19334", "93  O            -0.19730   \
1.53926"};
```

So I did:

```
Cases[%, Except[
  RegularExpression["[A-Z]" ~~ __Integer]], \[Infinity]].
```

But It did no work.

Comment: Please read: [(6998)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6998/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Pick[list1, StringFreeQ[#, RegularExpression["[A-Z]\\d"]] & /@ list1] 
Cases[list1, x_?(StringFreeQ[#, RegularExpression["[A-Z]\\d"]] &)]
Select[list1, StringFreeQ[#, RegularExpression["[A-Z]\\d"]] &]
DeleteCases[list1, x_?(!StringFreeQ[#, RegularExpression["[A-Z]\\d"]] &)]
```

and all of the above with `RegularExpression["[A-Z]\\d"]` replaced with

```
Alternatives @@ CharacterRange["A", "Z"] ~~ DigitCharacter
```

all give

```
Pick[list1, StringFreeQ[#, RegularExpression["[A-Z]\\d"]] & /@ list1] //Column
```

> [image]

where

```
list1 //Column
```

> [image]

Comment: I did not know th pick comand, is it new?

Comment: @user7096, `Pick` has been around since version 5; it is often more convenient/powerful than its older siblings `Select` and `Cases`.

Answer (score 5):

```
Select[list1,  StringFreeQ[#, ___ ~~ LetterCharacter ~~ DigitCharacter .. ~~ ___] &]

(*
90  O            -0.28487   1.23835
91  O            -0.23761   1.29381
92  O            -0.23093   1.19437
93  O            -0.19657   1.53843
94  O            -0.17235   1.46275
90  O            -0.28601   1.23805
91  O            -0.23863   1.29489
92  O            -0.23206   1.19334
93  O            -0.19730   1.53926
*)
```

Answer (score 2):

One can also use `StringReplace`

```
DeleteCases[StringReplace[list1, x___ ~~ LetterCharacter ~~ NumberString ~~ y___ :> ""], ""]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this but it looks like (for such specific list) that you can do it like this:

```
Select[list1, Xnor[StringMatchQ[#, "O" ~~ __]] &]
```