# Abbreviated expressions in StringCases?

Tags: string-manipulation

Am I missing something here? There's no support for abbreviated expressions in `StringCases?`

```
StringMatchQ["MATCH", "*H"]
```

(* True *)

versus

```
StringCases["MATCH", "*H"]
```

(* {}  *)

Comment: FWIW I noted this fact here: [(6999)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6999/121)

Answer (score 5):

You are not missing anything.  The documentation for [`StringCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringCases.html) does not state that it supports abbreviated expressions while [`StringMatchQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringMatchQ.html) does.

But you can use a string expression.

```
StringCases["MATCH", ___ ~~ "H"]
(* {"MATCH"} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

You are correct, `StringCases` does not support abbreviated string patterns.

Abbreviated string patterns date back to *Mathematica* version 1.  `StringExpression` was introduced in *Mathematica* version 5.1, largely obsoleting abbreviated patterns for string manipulation functions.  They still remain useful in other contexts such as file and symbol name manipulation.

A Google search reveals that the following functions are explicitly documented to support abbreviated string patterns: `StringMatchQ`, `FileNames`, `Clear`, `Protect`, `Import` (ZIP/TAR), `FindDevices`, `NameQ`, `Directory` and `Contexts`.  With the exception of `StringMatchQ`, none of these functions supports `StringExpression`.

Thus, `StringMatchQ` is an anomaly in that it is the only string manipulation function that supports abbreviated string patterns.  Mixing abbreviated and `StringExpression` patterns can be very confusing and lead to unexpected results.  Presumably, abbreviated pattern support in `StringMatchQ` was retained in the interest of backwards compatibility.  Newer functions only support the newer syntax and avoid the potential for confusion (e.g. `StringCases`, introduced alongside `StringExpression` in version 5.1).

It is possible to convert an abbreviated string pattern into a regular expression by means of the semi-documented function [StringPattern`PatternConvert](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html#337819047):

```
abbr[p_] := StringPattern`PatternConvert[p, None, 1][[1]] // RegularExpression

abbr["*H@X"]
(* RegularExpression["(?ms).*?H[^A-Z]+X"] *)
```

This lets us use abbreviated patterns with `StringCases`:

```
StringCases["MATCH", abbr["*H"]]
(* {"MATCH"} *)

StringCases["1X2X3X4X999X", abbr["@X"]]
(* {"1X", "2X", "3X", "4X", "999X"}
```

Comment: There is also `Names` that support both abbreviated string patterns and `StringExpression`, for example: ``Names["System`" ~~ Except[{"$", "`"}] .. ~~ "Style"]``.