# How to obtain earlier look for Virtual book in the latest documentation center?

Tags: documentation

In V 12.1, on windows, typing `tutorial/VirtualBookOverview` in the help windows shows this

[image]

Is it possible to obtain the earlier virtual book look, which is much nicer, since it is has expandable table to contents inline, so easier to view and navigate, as [shown here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6998/how-do-i-perform-string-matching-and-replacements) by Jens  (It seems new Virtual book was written using collection of notebooks, and hence missing table of contents (also called bookmarks in PDF files) which is very important for navigations of large documents). The first thing I do when I open a PDF file, is open the bookmarks view.

[image]

Comment: I have a dim recollection that b3m2a1 did this some time ago, but I can't find the relevant thread...